# Get the value of key from JSON response got from the curl url in unix Without using jq

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have written the shell script and getting JSON result from the curl.
I want to get the value of key form JSON response without using unix tools like jq, python etc.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what JSON do you have, what part do you want to extract and how does your current code fail? Please edit your post and show the [mcve].

Comment: @Corion Please have a look at the answer I posted and let me know if you have optimal solution.

Answer (score -1):

Got the **solution**,

I am getting following JSON response from curl and storing in variable :

CURL_OUTPUT='{ "url": "protocol://xyz.net/9999" , "other_key": "other_value" }'

**Question**  :I want to read the url key value and extract the id from that url:

**Answer** : _ID=$(echo $CURL_OUTPUT |awk '{print $2}' FS='url":' |awk '{print $1}' FS=',' | awk '{print $2}' FS='"'|awk '{print $4}' FS='/')

Comment: That is a bit of overkill -- 4 calls to `awk` and 4 calls to `printf` within a *command substitution* -- that's a minimum of 9-subshells spawned plus 4 pipes just to parse `'9999'`. Better to make a single call to `grep` assign the result to a temporary variable and then use the shell parameter expansion to delete up to the last `'/'`, e.g. `tmp=$(echo "$CURL_OUTPUT" | grep -o 'protocol[^", ]*'); _ID="${tmp##*/}"`